# Make a dataframe with elements of a list with a common columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to sort a set of data, which is given by a set of csv files.

The problem is to join all the elements of a list into a single new dataframe, maintaining a single date column that has a range for each element of the list.

The following code snippet creates two lists, *dflistcomplete* and *dflistpriceusd*, and uses a *for* loop to iterate through a list of previously fetched names (The "nombres" object is a list of the name of each of the csv files in the directory). Within the loop, a CSV file is read using the *read_csv* function of the Pandas library and the result is stored in a temporary *dataframe* called *temp_df*.

Then, the "PriceUSD" column is checked to see if it is present in the temporary dataframe with the *if* "PriceUSD" statement in *temp_df.columns*. If such a column is present, the CSV file is read again, but this time only the "time" and "PriceUSD" columns are included using the *usecols* argument. The result is stored in another temporary *dataframe* called *temp_df_priceusd*, and the column "PriceUSD" is renamed with the name found in the name list. Finally, the temporary dataframe is added to the *dflistpriceusd* list. If the column "PriceUSD" is not present in the temporary *dataframe*, the rest of the loop is skipped with the *continue* statement.

Finally, the original temporary dataframe is added to the *dflistcomplete* list. At the end of the loop, both lists will contain dataframes read from CSV files with specific names.

Attached is a "schematic" of how I intend to organise the data.

Many thanks in advance

[image: Schema]

```
dflistpriceusd = []
for i in range(len(nombres)):
    temp_df = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer = "csv221022/" + nombres[i] + ".csv",
                          header = 0,
                          sep = ",")
    if "PriceUSD" in temp_df.columns:
        temp_df_priceusd = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer = "csv221022/" + nombres[i] + ".csv",
                          header = 0,
                          usecols = ["time", "PriceUSD"],
                          sep = ",")
        temp_df_priceusd.rename(columns = {'PriceUSD': nombres[i]}, inplace = True)
        dflistpriceusd.append(temp_df_priceusd)

    else:
        continue
    dflistcompleto.append(temp_df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R:

```
## Bucle que crea objetos diferentes para cada CSV

for(file in files){
  dataframe <- read.csv(file, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  for(col in colnames(dataframe)){#checknombrecolumna
    if(col != "PriceUSD"){
    }
    else{
      ## Primero montar los dataframes y elegir solo dos columnas
      dataframe2 <- read.csv(file, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      dataframe2 <- dataframe2[c("time", "PriceUSD")]
      ## Configurar el nombre del objeto a "df_file"
      dfnames2 <- as.character(gsub("\\.csv$", "", file))
      prefijo <- as.character("df_")
      dfnames_final <- paste(c(prefijo, dfnames2), collapse = "")
      ## Cambiar el nombre de la columna "PriceUSD"
      prefijo = "Price"
      dfcolnames <- paste(c(prefijo, dfnames2), collapse = "")
      colnames(dataframe2)[colnames(dataframe2) == "PriceUSD"] <- dfcolnames
      ## Formar el objeto
      assign(dfnames_final, dataframe2)
    }
  }
}

## Eliminar los dataframes residuales del bucle anterior del environment
rm(dataframe, dataframe2, col, dfcolnames, dfnames_final, dfnames2, file, prefijo)

## Generar una lista con los objetos del environment que son un dataframe
environmentlist <- Filter(is.data.frame, mget(ls()))

## Ordenar las fechas de los dataframes
environmentlist <- lapply(environmentlist, function(x) arrange(x, time))

## Juntar todos los dataframes en uno solo
df_final <- reduce(environmentlist, full_join, by = "time")

## Cambiar el formato de la fecha
df_final$time <- as.Date(df_final$time, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

## Ordenar fechas del dataframe final
df_final <- arrange(df_final, time)
```

Comment: better add comments or description of your code that user who asked gets more in depth of your answer